# Sphinx joining indexes with certain logic

Tags: ruby, postgresql, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I've been researching and researching.. and I couldn't find a way to get results by
joining (as on sql with two tables) with some logic, I mean, I want to have a list of
results by matching "things" on the index A with the index B, for example:

**Index A** 
doc_id
thing A1
thing A2

**Index B** 
doc_id 
thing B1 
thing B2

And I want to get a list of all documents where "thing A1" match with "thing B1" for
example.

Pd: I'm using Postgres and Riddle ruby gem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx has no ability to join between indices, I'm afraid.

You can search across multiple indices at once, though. Another option would be to include the data you need from multiple database tables in a single Sphinx index. Would either of those options give you the results you're after? Or something close enough?

Comment: One can even say that Sphinx indexes are independent: no relation whatsoever between them.